# Traversing a Json Node using Javascript in marklogic?

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I want to traverse a JSON Node which is like this (i.e./node.json)

```
{
    "One": {
        "Name": "One",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    "Two": {
        "State": "kentucky"
    },
    "Three": {
        "Element1": "value1",
        "Element2": "value2",
        "Element3": "value3",
        "Element4": "value4",
        so on ...
    }
}
```

**Updated**
My Usecase : I tried to run a CORB job with below configurations

Transform.xqy (Where I am keeping all the elements in an array)

```
var name = fn.tokenize(URI, ";");
const node = cts.doc(name);
var a= node.xpath("/One/*");
var b= node.xpath("/Two/*");
var c= node.xpath("/Three/*");
fn.stringJoin([a, b, c,name], " , ")
```

When started running the CORB job to create CSV file for 1.3 M documents in my marklogic DB, it is a never ending story.

Comment: explain the tokenize on the uri.

Comment: Since i am passing URI's in batches it will be default delimted with `;` ,So i am separating them in my transform module.

Comment: but then name is a sequence and node is  sequence - but you are not iterating over a sequence in your sample code..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Thought `name` will we send one by one to `node`. Will implement in `for loop` and let u know the performance

Comment: See new answer with the iteration over uris. The spread operator ... is also what I used to flatten the three arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated to use batch from Corb

OK. Based on more info in the ticket:
(1) You are not iterating over the uris
(2) You are doing a join on a nested array. Seems odd.

My Example doc:

```
declareUpdate()
let obj = {
    One: {
        Name: "One",
        Country: "US"
    },
    Two: {
        State: "kentucky"
    },
    Three: {
        Element1: "value1",
        Element2: "value2",
        Element3: "value3",
        Element4: "value4"
    }
}

xdmp.documentInsert('/test1.json', obj)
xdmp.documentInsert('/test2.json', obj)
```

Based on the example, code that I think would work in your module. The uris is to mimic the batched uris coming from Corb:

```
let uris= '/test1.json;/test2.json'
let rows = uris.split(';')
rows.map(uri => {
  let obj = fn.head(fn.doc(uri)).toObject()
  return   [
              ...Object.keys(obj.One).map(k => obj.One[k]),
              ...Object.keys(obj.Two).map(k => obj.Two[k]),
              ...Object.keys(obj.Three).map(k => obj.Three[k])               
           ].join(',')
}).join('\n')
```

Resulting in:

```
One,US,kentucky,value1,value2,value3,value4    
One,US,kentucky,value1,value2,value3,value4
```

Comment: As you said `You are doing a join on a nested array. Seems Odd` Can you suggest any better approach for my requirement ?

Comment: The spread operator I used no my example flattens the Tray for you. That's what those three dots do in my example

Comment: Thanks @David the code snippet optimized my corb  `ALOT`. Are there any documentation in ML regarding `MAP` implementation in `JS` like you had mentioned above?

Comment: Hi Seeker. MarkLogic comes with the Google V8 javascript engine compiled in. My example is not ML Specific in that way. The best main resource is here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript.

Comment: Here is the MarkLogic specific page as well: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/functions

Comment: Hi David, One clarification: whatever corb is doing above , we can able to achieve the same using server side JavaScript calling through ML-Java API ?

Comment: @Seeker - yes, the code is generic.  How you execute it, collect it and write your file would be up to you. Corb, Java Client API, etc.  Corb came from your other post where you wanted a way to do this and I gave you the 'Hello World' example where you could affect this from the command line with evaluated scripts and Corb. You talked about millions of records. Corb or the data movement SDK does the heavy lifting for you across the nodes. Getting the same performance on your own and playing nicely with the cluster (not consuming all resources) is fine, but will just take more elbow grease.

Comment: Thanks @David ,Since i am newbie to JS, Just one question regarding your above `row.map` function working. As my understanding you are creating a map for `rows` since it is a sequence of URI's. And you went in to the `rows.map` then you had created a `uri` variable where it will store all the values from the arrays delimited by `,`, and then atlast you are joining all the `uri's` output  with `/n`. Correct me if i am wrong . .

Comment: In a nutshell, I converted a uri to a comma-separated list of the document's content. [line 3] The iteration was done by the map function, [line 4] Read the doc. [line 6,7,8]This then got changed to a flat array of values using the spread operator (joined 3 arrays basically) and then turned that into the comma separated list via the [line 9]join with the comma. At this point, I had an array of strings with comma separated values. [line 10]I then turned that array into a string of rows (joining on the line return)